# 15.04 Errors upgrating or installing any package

Tags: apt, upgrade, 15.04

I can't install or upgrade. I tried purge autoclean clean cash but nothing any tips?

```
    Preconfiguring packages ...
Setting up util-linux (2.25.2-4ubuntu3) ...
insserv: warning: script 'K01cinestart' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'S13poderosa-sites' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'poderosa-sites' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: script docker: service docker already provided!
insserv: warning: script 'cinestart' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop at service grub-common if started
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Max recursions depth 99 reached
insserv:  loop involving service nfs-kernel-server at depth 7
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service grub-common and urandom if started
insserv:  loop involving service urandom at depth 4
insserv:  loop involving service hwclock at depth 3
insserv: There is a loop between service poderosa-sites and udev if started
insserv:  loop involving service udev at depth 1
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv:  loop involving service mountdevsubfs at depth 3
insserv:  loop involving service mountkernfs at depth 1
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop at service poderosa-sites if started
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv:  loop involving service networking at depth 6
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting poderosa-sites depends on grub-common and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package util-linux (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 util-linux
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Let me guess, is a failed upgrade from Ubuntu 14 to 15.04?

Comment: Not really the upgrade work fine (I think) .  But yes it was an upgrade from 14

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`Switch on` your computer.

`Press` and `hold` the `Shift key`, which will bring up the `Grub menu`.

`Select` the line which starts with `Advanced options`.

`Select` the line ending with `(recovery mode)`

`Press` `Return` and your computer will begin the boot process.

Your workstation should display a `menu` with a number of `options`.

One of the options will be `Check all file systems`. `Press` `Return` with this option `highlighted`.

Next,other of the options will be `Enable networking`. `Press` `Return` with this option `highlighted`.

Next, other of the options will be `Drop to root shell prompt`. `Press` `Return` with this option `highlighted`.

In the terminal, enter the commands

```
mount -o remount,rw /
mount --all
apt-get purge util-linux
apt-get update
apt-get -f install
apt-get -m install
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
```

Comment: Hi kyodake, thanks a lot for your answer when i press check all files systems stays in the console for hrs is that normal.  I get ok on started load and ok - started flash and after and then kind of die...

Comment: then i got the following error The folowing packages have unmet dependencies. policykit-1 : Depends: libpam-systemd but is not going to be installed E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated braeaks, this may be caused by ld packeges

Comment: Try this: open the /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log with nano text editor. 'nano  /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log', locate any broken packages and remove them with:  'apt-get remove package'.